# FF 45 + Selenium 2.53 stopped working

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow, specrun

Well, from last one week i was working on updating my scripts for FF to 45 and selenium webdriver to 2.53 and selenium support to 2.53 as well and i was done with it and suddenly FF45 stopped working . Like it open up the browser but not entering the URL . looks like it firefox instantiation problem but then how come it was working up until now ? i havent changed anything in my config at all. When i run it from jenkins it is giving error like ,https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build  and Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

my package details are as below .

```
<packages>
  <package id="ExtentReports" version="2.41.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="FluentAssertions" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ImpromptuInterface" version="6.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="6.9.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.0.12054" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ReportUnit" version="1.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Selenium.Support" version="2.51.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="2.51.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SpecFlow" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic" version="1.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SpecFlow.NUnit" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SpecFlow.Plus.Excel" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SpecRun.Runner" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SpecRun.SpecFlow.1-9-0" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

just debugged my code and it is giving below error.
    {"Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown."}

can any one able to help ?

Comment: have you disable browser auto update?

Comment: Your package list shows selenium 2.51.0 as your current version, are you sure you've updated to 2.53.0?

Comment: @Mobrockers sorry it is 2.51 due to i was trying to downgrade and see if that works or not . but actually it is 2.53. i tried just now and it is not working .

Comment: @4M01 yes Auto update is disabled .

Comment: if you are getting a stackoverflow exception then you must have changed something in your calling code. without some addtional details its hard to help. Have you simply debugged the process to see where it is failing? and what the call stack is at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade FF version into 46.. it will work

Comment: He's not using firefox 47.

Comment: @Mobrockers you saying i should use FF47?

Comment: Im using FF version 46.0.1 +Selenium 2.53 its working for me